# Is it possible to modularize world files?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It would be useful if I could define kind of basic world in one file and then include this world file in other world files that would add different models and configuration to the simulation. Is there any way how to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20838/is-it-possible-to-modularize-world-files?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2018-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There isn't yet a way to include a file into another through an `<include>` tag for example, just like it's done for models.

One thing which we've done in the past is to use embedded Ruby to generate world files from a template. This allows separating bits of the world into different templates, but the final generated world is always one.

You can see an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/servicesim/src/7f74a88af2e775320fbe52932db439055293b84d/servicesim_competition/worlds/?at=default). And [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/servicesim/wiki/Scenario%20generation) are instructions on how to get started with it.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1